# Chrome: Save custom CSS changes made in the inspector tool so they appear on page reload

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to modify some CSS of Youtube so an extension I use is in a better position relative to the video. Can I make CSS changes in the inspector window and then save it somewhere so it's always used when I visit Youtube.com? thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only Chrome's inspector window, this isn't possible. However, using an extension might solve your problem. [This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld) plugin seems to do exactly what you want.

Note: I have not tested this solution on your use case, I don't know if it is possible to change the position of a custom extension, or only the css of the standard page. Might depend on the priority/order in which your extensions are loaded.

Comment: GOLDEN! it's working perfect, thanks so much this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Here what did the trick for me in Opera 85 (should probably work similarly in other Chromium-based browsers):

To save your custom CSS, you can go to the "Sources" tab of inspector and find there "inspector-stylesheet" file - there you should have all your modified styles, which you can copy. Then you can use an extensions like "Stylus" to paste it into a new user style for the URL - and make these styles permanent for you.